# I want to display the index (number) of each child when i click it

Tags: javascript, foreach, parent-child, indexof, nodelist

Here I have a parent which contains a few children.
I want to display the index (number) of each child on the console by clicking on it.
i tried to use forEach method to detect the clicked child, but when i try to get the index of the child that i clicked it does not work. I tried indexOf() method but it shows an error

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
let children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
children.forEach(child => {
    child.onclick = function () {
      console.log( /* children.indexOf(child) */ ) 
      // this is the method i tried but it didn't worked
     
      console.log( /*here i want to display the index of the clicked child */ );
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">a</div>
    <div class="child">b</div>
    <div class="child">c</div>
    <div class="child">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Always tag your questions with the programming language. It will ensure far more people get to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert `children` from a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) into an array (using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
let children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
children.forEach(child => {
    child.onclick = function () {
      console.log(Array.from(children).indexOf(child));
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">a</div>
    <div class="child">b</div>
    <div class="child">c</div>
    <div class="child">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done, it works fine :)